# PowerShell click form submit URL incorrect

Tags: powershell

**Tl:dr: I need to be able to submit a HTML form using PowerShell when the `action` parameter doesn't contain the full domain name.**

I want to click the `votea` button in the following form using PowerShell:

```
<form action="submit.aspx#submittop" method="post" id="submit-control-form" name="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="add_id" value="123456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="nextfive" value="<form action="submit.aspx#submittop" method="post" id="submit-control-form" name="form1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="add_id" value="123456789">
                            <input type="hidden" name="nextfive" value="123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,70974215,123456789,123456789,123456789,69717999,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,91092904,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789">
                            <input type="hidden" name="p_Id" value="123456789">
                            <input type="hidden" name="u_Id" value="123456789">
                            <input type="hidden" name="sp_Id" value="1234">
                            <input type="hidden" name="lv_dt" value="04/01/2016 08:57:23 AM">
                            <input type="hidden" name="username_vote" value="someusername">
                            <input type="hidden" name="h" value="0">
                            <input type="hidden" name="s" value="0">

                            <button type="submit" class="submit-no-button" id="submit-button-no-var" name="votec" value="3">No</button>

                            <button type="submit" class="submit-yes-button" id="submit-button-yes-var" name="votea" value="1">Yes</button>                                  



                        </form>">
    <input type="hidden" name="p_Id" value="123456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="u_Id" value="123456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="sp_Id" value="1234">
    <input type="hidden" name="lv_dt" value="04/01/2016 08:57:23 AM">
    <input type="hidden" name="username_vote" value="someusername">
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="0">  



</form>
```

Here's my source code:

```
function Invoke-DomainLogin([Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential){

    $URL = "example.com"

    $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Credential.Password)
    $ptPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    $LoginBody = @{

        username = $Credential.UserName
        password = $ptPassword

    }


    Do {

        $Login = Invoke-WebRequest $URL/viewrespond.aspx -SessionVariable Domain -Method Post -Body $LoginBody

        if ($Login.Content -like "*Your email or password were entered incorrectly*"){

            Throw "Credentials incorrect"

        }

        $submit = Invoke-WebRequest ($mmURL = "$URL/submit.aspx#submittop") -WebSession $Domain -Method Post


        $Click = $submit.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName("button")|Where-Object {$_.name -eq "votea"}

        $Click.click()

        $Obj = New-Object PSObject

        $Obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Username -Value ($submit.Forms|Where-Object Id -eq "submit-control-form").Fields.username_vote
        $Obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Link     -Value ("{0}/{1}" -f $URL,($submit.Links|Where-Object innerHtml -Eq "View Profile").href)

        $Obj

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    }
    while($fakestring -ne "fakestring")


}

Invoke-DomainLogin $Cred
```

When I execute `$Click.click()`, unless I have IE set as my default browser, I get the dialog box for opening a file, asking me which application I want to use (What?!) - So I set my default browser to IE temporarily and I found that the form action URL is missing the domain name, so the URL in the browser would be `/submit.aspx#submittop` and not contain the URL because the form action URL doesn't have the full domain name specified.

I don't have access to change the form in any way, how can I get PowerShell to manipulate the action url in the form so it's `example.com/submit.aspx#submittop`?

Comment: So just a little help. No need for that marshal calls for the secure string
`$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password` will get you password in plain text

Comment: Another tip . You can one line new PSObjects like `New-Object PSObject -Property @{Username ="Hello"; Link="World"}`

Comment: Thanks for your advice! - I'll add that in!

Comment: This might be hard to help with since I need to find a similar case in order to troubleshoot.

Comment: In short, I just need to be able to click on a button element in a HTML form when the action URL doesn't contain `example.com`

Comment: Let me tell you what i think is happening. The action is being prevented in javascript and the submit is taking place in javascript. Since the page in powershell is not running the js the submit action will fail. The submit action looks like a anchor to the top of the current page. Making me think its a ajax call taking place. Also in the `form value="<form action="submit.aspx#submittop" ....` would be invalid

Comment: So what will need to be done is you need to parse the Javascript and find where the submit is happening. OR you can use the developer tools in chrome, IR , or firefox ....submit page manually and view the post and build a post from that OR you can run this in IE using COM in powershell